# An equivalent condition of the intersection of convex hulls of two compact sets being empty

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convex-hulls

I came across the following problem where $A$ and $B$ are two compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ('compact' here means 'closed and bounded'). We need to show that there exists a nonzero vector $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a scalar $b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\mathbf{a}^{\top}\mathbf{x}-b \leq -1 ~ \forall \mathbf{x} \in A \text{ and } \mathbf{a}^{\top}\mathbf{x}-b \geq 1 ~ \forall \mathbf{x} \in B,$$
if and only if the intersection of the convex hull of $A$ and the convex hull of $B$ is empty.

I think it is similar to the Separating hyperplane theorem of convex sets. However, I cannot figure out where the $-1$ and $1$ comes from. Maybe the proof of this statement is far from the Separating hyperplane theorem? Any useful suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It is just the usual separation theorem you can find in Rudin's FA. A simple transformation can be used to get $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain more about the 'simple transformation' to get -1 and +1, which I'm still confused about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove this from standard version of a separation theorem you can do the following:  If $a^{T}x-b \leq \alpha$ on $A$ and $a^{T}x-b \geq \beta$ on $B$ with $\beta >\alpha$ apply the map $f(t)=\frac 2 {\beta-\alpha} t-1-\frac {2\alpha}  {\beta-\alpha}$ to these inequalities. Since $f$ is increasing the inequalities remain valid after aplying $f$ to both sides.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have two more questions. First, when applying the map to both sides, $a^{T}x-b$ is also changed, so that it is not the original inequality. Second, the standard version of separation theorem is about two convex sets, while  here $A$, $B$ are arbitrary compact sets and we are talking about their convex hulls. Sorry to bother but I'm fresh in this area. It would be appreciated if you could reply.

Comment: When you apply $f$ to $a^{T}x-b$ you get $a'^{T}x-b'$ for some $a',b'$. Can you figure out what $a'$ and $b'$ are ?  I am using the fact that convex hulls of compact sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$ are themselves compact. This is proved in Rudin's book. Once you know this you can apply the separation theorem to the convex hulls of $A$ and $B$. @Arthur556

Comment: Thank you very much.